# display the contents of a sqlite3 database according to the dates

Tags: sqlite

I use python 3.6 and sqlite3, and I have a problem when I want to read the content of the table between 2 variables
first, when I use two string format dates ("2019-01-01" and "2019-05-20") the following code works correctly :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import time
import calendar
import sqlite3
import datetime

fen = Tk()
fen.title('ILS system ')
fen.resizable(0,0)
largeur=920
hauteur=660
fen.geometry('{}x{}+0+0'.format(largeur,hauteur))

def CreateTable_releves():

    conn1_releves = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test.db')
    curseur1_releves = conn1_releves.cursor()
    curseur1_releves.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS releves (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,time_releves TEXT NOT NULL, monitor1_releves TEXT NOT NULL,monitor2_releves TEXT NOT NULL)''')
    curseur1_releves.close()


def Add_To_Table_releves():

    time_releves_get = str(date_choisie_ils35R)

    monitor1_releves_get = str(ent_releves_mesure_mon1_axe_loc35R.get())
    monitor2_releves_get = str(ent_releves_mesure_mon2_axe_loc35R.get())

    conn2_releves = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test.db')
    curseur2_releves = conn2_releves.cursor()
    curseur2_releves.execute('''INSERT INTO releves (time_releves,monitor1_releves,monitor2_releves) VALUES (?,?,?)''',(time_releves_get,monitor1_releves_get,monitor2_releves_get))
    conn2_releves.commit()
    curseur2_releves.close()

# CreateTable_releves()

def monitoring () :

    fen_monitoring=Toplevel(fen)
    fen_monitoring.title('ddm axe')
    fen_monitoring.geometry('450x400+300+150')

    s= Scrollbar(fen_monitoring)
    T= Text(fen_monitoring,bg='powder blue',width=450,height=400)
    s.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    s.config(command=T.yview)
    T.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)

    def update_releves():

        T.delete('1.0', END)
        T.update()

        conn = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test.db')
        curseur = conn.cursor()     
        for resultats in curseur.execute('SELECT * FROM releves  where  time_releves between "2019-01-01" AND "2019-05-20" ORDER BY time_releves DESC'):  

            contenu_table_releves= str(resultats[1])+"\t\t"+ str(resultats[2])+"\t\t"+ str(resultats[3])+"\n"

            T.insert(END,contenu_table_releves)  
        T.after(1000,update_releves)
        curseur.close()

    update_releves()

bt=Button(fen,text='click on\nthe button', command=monitoring)
bt.pack()
```

here is the image of the contents of the toplevel window :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiA72.jpg)

but if I modify the code by input two variables (first_day) and (last_day) in the sql requet :

```
for resultats in curseur.execute('SELECT * FROM releves  where  time_releves between "first_day" AND "last_day" ORDER BY time_releves DESC'):
```

there is the complet modify code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import time
import calendar
import sqlite3
import datetime

fen = Tk()
fen.title('ILS system ')
fen.resizable(0,0)
largeur=920
hauteur=660
fen.geometry('{}x{}+0+0'.format(largeur,hauteur))

#to calculate first and last day of the month:
now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_month = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, 1)
date_on_next_month = start_month + datetime.timedelta(35)
start_next_month = datetime.datetime(date_on_next_month.year, date_on_next_month.month, 1)
last_day_month = start_next_month - datetime.timedelta(1)
last_day=last_day_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
first_day=start_month = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def CreateTable_releves():

    conn1_releves = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test.db')
    curseur1_releves = conn1_releves.cursor()
    curseur1_releves.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS releves (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,time_releves TEXT NOT NULL, monitor1_releves TEXT NOT NULL,monitor2_releves TEXT NOT NULL)''')
    curseur1_releves.close()


def Add_To_Table_releves():

    time_releves_get = str(date_choisie_ils35R)

    monitor1_releves_get = str(ent_releves_mesure_mon1_axe_loc35R.get())
    monitor2_releves_get = str(ent_releves_mesure_mon2_axe_loc35R.get())

    conn2_releves = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test.db')
    curseur2_releves = conn2_releves.cursor()
    curseur2_releves.execute('''INSERT INTO releves (time_releves,monitor1_releves,monitor2_releves) VALUES (?,?,?)''',(time_releves_get,monitor1_releves_get,monitor2_releves_get))
    conn2_releves.commit()
    curseur2_releves.close()

# CreateTable_releves()

def monitoring () :

    fen_monitoring=Toplevel(fen)
    fen_monitoring.title('ddm axe')
    fen_monitoring.geometry('450x400+300+150')

    s= Scrollbar(fen_monitoring)
    T= Text(fen_monitoring,bg='powder blue',width=450,height=400)
    s.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    s.config(command=T.yview)
    T.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)

    def update_releves():

        T.delete('1.0', END)
        T.update()

        conn = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test.db')
        curseur = conn.cursor()     
        for resultats in curseur.execute('SELECT * FROM releves  where  time_releves between "first_day" AND "last_day" ORDER BY time_releves DESC'):  

            contenu_table_releves= str(resultats[1])+"\t\t"+ str(resultats[2])+"\t\t"+ str(resultats[3])+"\n"

            T.insert(END,contenu_table_releves)  
        T.after(1000,update_releves)
        curseur.close()

    update_releves()

bt=Button(fen,text='click on\nthe button', command=monitoring)
bt.pack()
```

the toplevel window appear but empty like in the next picture :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lNdc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code so that it is clearer by integrating widget (entry, button), and then I added the setpoint of "R Spark". I had as a result the following code which apparently works for the moment. (I will redo other tests soon)
if there are any comments about this new this would be welcome.

The new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import time
import calendar
import sqlite3
import datetime

fen = Tk()
fen.title('ILS system ')
fen.resizable(0,0)
largeur=920
hauteur=660
fen.geometry('{}x{}+0+0'.format(largeur,hauteur))

#to calculate first and last day of the month:
now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_month = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, 1)
date_on_next_month = start_month + datetime.timedelta(35)
start_next_month = datetime.datetime(date_on_next_month.year, date_on_next_month.month, 1)
last_day_month = start_next_month - datetime.timedelta(1)
last_day=last_day_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
first_day=start_month = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def CreateTable_releves():

    conn1_releves = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test/test.db')
    curseur1_releves = conn1_releves.cursor()
    curseur1_releves.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS releves (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,time_releves TEXT NOT NULL, monitor1_releves TEXT NOT NULL,monitor2_releves TEXT NOT NULL)''')
    curseur1_releves.close()

def Add_To_Table_releves():

    time_releves_get = str(date_choisie.get())
    monitor1_releves_get = str(ent_mon1_mesure.get())
    monitor2_releves_get = str(ent_mon2_mesure.get())

    conn2_releves = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test/test.db')
    curseur2_releves = conn2_releves.cursor()
    curseur2_releves.execute('''INSERT INTO releves (time_releves,monitor1_releves,monitor2_releves) VALUES (?,?,?)''',(time_releves_get,monitor1_releves_get,monitor2_releves_get))
    conn2_releves.commit()
    curseur2_releves.close()

CreateTable_releves()

def monitoring () :

    fen_monitoring=Toplevel(fen)
    fen_monitoring.title('ddm axe')
    fen_monitoring.geometry('450x400+300+150')

    s= Scrollbar(fen_monitoring)
    T= Text(fen_monitoring,bg='powder blue',width=450,height=400)
    s.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    s.config(command=T.yview)
    T.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)

    def update_releves():

        T.delete('1.0', END)
        T.update()

        conn = sqlite3.connect('bdd/test/test.db')
        curseur = conn.cursor()     
        for resultats in curseur.execute('SELECT * FROM releves where time_releves between ? AND ? ORDER BY time_releves DESC;', (first_day, last_day)):  

            contenu_table_releves= str(resultats[1])+"\t\t"+ str(resultats[2])+"\t\t"+ str(resultats[3])+"\n"

            T.insert(END,contenu_table_releves)  
        T.after(1000,update_releves)
        curseur.close()

    update_releves()

ent_mon1_mesure=StringVar()
ent_mon2_mesure=StringVar()
date_choisie=StringVar()

ent_mon1=Entry(fen,textvariable=ent_mon1_mesure)
ent_mon1.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW,padx=10,pady=10)

ent_mon2=Entry(fen,textvariable=ent_mon2_mesure)
ent_mon2.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW,padx=10,pady=10)

ent_time_releve=Entry(fen,textvariable=date_choisie)
ent_time_releve.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW,padx=10,pady=10)

bt_valider=Button(fen,text='valider', command=Add_To_Table_releves)
bt_valider.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)

bt_monitoring=Button(fen,text='afficher monitoring', command=monitoring)
bt_monitoring.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)

fen.mainloop()
```

Thanks R Spark for help